# LED light and LCD not turning on at the same time

Tags: arduino

In my circuit if an object comes a certain distance, the LED light will turn on and the LCD display will show the distance.

The problem is if the LED light is turned on with 11.1V power, the LCD display will dim and not show distance. If the LCD displays distance and is not dim, the LED light will not turn on.

Can you help me solve this? Images of the circuit and picture of setup below.

The 11.1V from battery goes to a buck converter where 5V is transferred to the Arduino, then attached to LED lights and an LCD display and distance sensor.

A transistor will amplify voltage to LED lights from Arduino.

[image: circuit]

[image: breadboard]

Comment: The LM317 is not a buck converter.  It is a linear regulator.

Comment: Where are the 6 LEDs in your breadboard picture? Also I would strongly advise to throw this breadboard out the window and pick up soldering. The wiring here is a complete mess and a very likely source of constant problems.

Comment: As you have ti set up, your 12V LEDs are never getting more than 5V.

Comment: 9V batteries are not intended for high current use.

Comment: The Arduino UNO has an input for higher voltage - it has its own regulator.  You don't need to supply it with 5V.

Comment: An yep, LM317 is not a buck, it's an ugly old goat :)

Comment: Your LM317 is not connected properly. It will not output 5V in your setup. Please consult [the LM317 data sheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm317-d.pdf). There should also not be a resistor between the output of the LM317 and the Arduino (as looks to be the case on your breadboard setup). Why is it there? The transistors will also not work very well in your current setup, as noted by JRE and Michal's answer. What kind of battery management system are you intending to use that will work with 9V batteries?

Comment: @StarCat OP is not using LM317, the photo shows one of these fake counterfeit "LM2596" modules. Also the transistor doesn't look like 2N3055, and it is wired on the wrong side of the LED on the schematic.

Comment: @bobflux, It's hard to see but I think you're right, thanks. I agree there's a lot of room for improvement here ;-)

Comment: `If the LCD displays distance and is not dim, the LED light will not turn on.` ... your thinking is flawed  ... that should say `If the LED light does not turn on, then the LCD displays distance and is not dim.`

Answer (score 0):

Your LEDs must have series resistors. You must decide how much current you wish to draw through them, then check their forward voltage and calculate suitable resistor values.

Right now you are feeding the LEDs as much current as this BMS can deliver, so you have likely destroyed them or damaged them.

Answer (score 0):

To control the Leds with 5V you must use common emitter connection. Otherwise the Leds will be supplied with 4v3 only (5-Vbe).

Pick the R2 according the Led current with enough wattage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f14nZn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>